# Why I can not register gitlab-runner? 10.0.2.3:53: server misbehaving

Tags: ubuntu, docker, http

I have setup Gitlab server on My Vagrant VM. When I try to register

```
sudo docker exec -t -i gitlab-runner gitlab-runner register
```

I have problems

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=https:// status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab-miki/api/v4/runners: Post https://gitlab-miki/api/v4/runners: dial tcp: lookup gitlab-miki on 10.0.2.3:53: server misbehaving
```

My IP is actually `inet 10.10.1.79`
ip addr show

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:6d:95:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 81734sec preferred_lft 81734sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe6d:95c4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:de:34:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.1.79/24 brd 10.10.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fede:34e3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Why is server misbehaving?

Comment: Are you using kube-dns?

Comment: No,I am not.I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue/error msg which seemed to be saying that the gitlab server couldn't be found.

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 
runner=XXXX status=couldn't execute POST against http://YYYY/api/v4/runners: Post "http://YYYY/api/v4/runners": dial tcp: lookup YYYY on 192.168.Z.Z:53: server misbehaving
PANIC: Failed to register the runner.
```

The GitLab server hostname (which in your case is gitlab-miki) could not be resolved for some reason even though I defined in the GitLab Runner box's /etc/hosts file.

(On the GitLab server under settings->CI/CD->Runners->Specific runners->2. Register the runner with this URL it was showing the address with the server's hostname and not IP address)

I solved the issue by simply replacing the host name (gitlab-miki) with the IP of the GitLab server during the registration process.